# C and pointer notation

Tags: c, pointers

Opening up the Postgres codebase, I see that much of the C code is written by having pointers with the -> notation in such a way that:

```
(foo)->next = 5;
```

I know that pointer notation has levels of precedence, such that -> = (*foo). and is not the same as *foo.

However, does it mean anything when the parentheses are outside the variable name and de-referencing the address of next or is it merely a convention that is endemic to a coding style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a coding convention that I've not seen before.

But it doesn't change anything.

```
(foo)->next = 5;
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
foo->next = 5;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That's what I thought, and found it especially strange since it was everywhere in the codebase.

Comment: To expand on it, the reason you'd use this construct is as a safety-belt in case foo is a macro. It's the same reason some C style guides (for example FreeBSD's) suggest that all return statements be of the form return (x); instead of just return x;

Comment: Although if `foo` were a macro, it would be wise to have it fully parenthesized, e.g. `#define foo (blargity->blah)`

Answer (score 2):

It is a coding convention for safety.

In simple code, where foo is just a pointer, the parens are redundant.

```
(foo)->next = 5;
```

However, consider if there is or *was* the chance that foo might be defined by a macro so it is a more complex expression.

In that case, the parens might be required to avoid a compiler error or, worse, to avoid incorrect precedence. Imagine if it translated to an ugly expression like:

```
( ++get_foo() )->next = 5;
```

or a common cast:

```
( (db_record*)foo_ptr )->next = 5;
```

Something to bear in mind with *idiomatic* C code is that macros were often used as an abstraction mechanism for things we might do more explicitly in other languages ;-)

Comment: Any macro that _doesn't_ parenthesize it's expansion is a problem. IMHO it should be the macro's job to ensure its own use safety, not the macro-caller's job.

Answer (score 1):

It is meaningless. The parenthesis have no effect since the expression inside them is so simple. It's basically

```
(*(foo)).next = 5;
```

Which, as you can see, is an extraneous set of parenthesis. If that's how the project is doing it, go for it. Otherwise, I think it looks rather awful, so I would try not to use it.

Comment: Did you mean '`(*(foo)).next = 5;`'?

Comment: Oh. Right. At least now I feel like there's a reason I can't focus on my homework. Thanks for pointing it out, and thanks to Robert for fixing it.